# Detect if PWA is hosted in WebView2

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, webview2

Is it possible, from JavaScript, to detect if a PWA is being executed in WebView2 host or in a browser?

Comment: You can always try checking the useragent. But as the developer can set the useragent to whatever value pleases, it might not be 100% reliable